# The kerberos option is deprecated on smbclient, but is the only option working!

Tags: samba, kerberos

On Slackware 15 (Samba version 4.15.10) I want to do smbclient, with gssapi/kerberos auth.
Of course the kerberos client cache is aready set at login
and I can see the file cache in tmp dir.
Pam are configured to use pam_krb5 for password session and auth

If I use the new --use-kerberos..ask for password!

```
smbclient -U pino --use-kerberos=required \\\\myhost\\Pub 
Password for [MYDOM\pino]:
```

If I remove -U pino, I do sudo su - Pino or login with Pino, same thing.

If I use the deprecated -k..works

```
smbclient -U pino -k \\\\myhost\\Pub 
    Password for [MYDOM\pino]:
    WARNING: The option -k|--kerberos is deprecated!
    Try "help" to get a list of possible commands.
    smb: \>
```

How to enter using kerberos..without -k?

EDIT: probably is a bug..or my misconfiguration, but using
smbclient -U pino \\myhost\Pub

ask for password..I press enter and use kerberos!

case 1: with ticket, ask for pass..I press enter and use kerberos

```
smbclient  \\\\myhost\\Pub
Password for [pino@MYHOST.PRIV]:
Try "help" to get a list of possible commands.
smb: \>
```

case 2: kdestroy, auth fail (and is logical, OK, right)

```
kdestroy
smbclient  \\\\myhost\\Pub
Password for [pino@MYHOST.PRIV]:
gensec_spnego_client_negTokenInit_step: Could not find a suitable mechtype in NEG_TOKEN_INIT
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER
```

Now the question is..why is still ask for password?

Comment: On Slackware 15 Samba is version 4.15.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm at a disadvantage here because on the machine I've got for testing I'm running an earlier version of `smbclient` (4.9.5-Debian). However, according to the [man page on samba.org](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smbclient.1.html) it seems that the preferred replacement for a standalone `-k` is to indicate *how* you want to use Kerberos:

> **`--use-kerberos=desired|required|off`** This parameter determines whether Samba client tools will try to authenticate using Kerberos. For Kerberos authentication you need to use dns names instead of IP addresses when connecting to a service.
>
> Note that specifying this parameter here will override the `client use kerberos` parameter in the `${prefix}/etc/smb.conf` file.

So, I would expect that you should use a scenario a bit like this,

```
kinit user@CONTOSO.COM    # Domain in capitals. Provide password
smbclient --use-kerberos=required '\\SERVER\Share'
```

Note that if I use the older form of the `smbclient` command I do not get prompted for a password:

```
smbclient -k '\\SERVER\Share'
```

This difference to your situation suggests to me that your `kinit` failed or the ticket is out of date. Rather than relying on the presence of a file in `/tmp`, run `klist` to confirm the validity of your ticket:

```
klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1001
Default principal: roaima@CONTOSO.COM

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
28/10/22 17:25:55  29/10/22 03:25:55  krbtgt/CONTOSO.COM@CONTOSO.COM
        renew until 29/10/22 17:25:52
28/10/22 17:26:05  29/10/22 03:25:55  cifs/DC@CONTOSO.COM
```

Comment: Ticket is ok, otherwise -k doesn't work

Comment: It doesn't work for me. `Smbclient Version 4.19.2-Debian`.

My `impacket-smbclient` works perfectly at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Solution found.

Use of kerberos required (is possible also to set permanent in smb.conf thanks to user roaima). And -N don't ask for a pass.

```
echo mypass|kinit
Password for pino@MYHOST.PRIV: 
smbclient -N --use-kerberos=required '\\myhost.priv\myshare'
Try "help" to get a list of possible commands.
smb: \>
```

works fine also with the "old" syntax

```
 echo mypass|kinit
 Password for pino@MYHOST.PRIV: 
 smbclient -N --use-kerberos=required \\\\MYHOST\\myshare
 Try "help" to get a list of possible commands.
 smb: \>
```